# How can i use batch_size in my LSTM algorithm?

Tags: python, matlab, artificial-intelligence, lstm, backpropagation

I have some problems about batch size in LSTM algorithm. I'm trying to implement NLP with LSTM and i don't know how to use batch size in the code below. Can anyone help me with this?

In this code, i have mxn input matrix and with the time series, we can say n time series (mx1) vector with 1 batch. But how can i implement for more batch size and update weight according to batches? Will i continue feedforward calculation with (batch * timeseries) time? Also how will i process back propogation section with these batches? Am i need to refresh cell informations for every batches?

I don't want to use keras or tensorflow for now, i want to design my own algorithm.

The code is in MATLAB format but i will convert it in python language.

Thanks in advance.

```
%feed forward section (for 1 batch):

TimeSeries = 32;

for t=2:TimeSeries
   a(:,t)=tanh(Wa*x(:,t)+Ua*out(:,t-1)+ba);
   i(:,t)=SigFunc(Wi*x(:,t)+Ui*out(:,t-1)+bi);
   f(:,t)=SigFunc(Wf*x(:,t)+Uf*out(:,t-1)+bf);
   o(:,t)=SigFunc(Wo*x(:,t)+Uo*out(:,t-1)+bo);

   state(:,t)=a(:,t).*i(:,t)+f(:,t).*state(:,t-1);
   out(:,t)=tanh(state(:,t)).*o(:,t);
   Delta(:,t)=out(:,t)-ResOut(:,t);
end
```